# Why does `\makecell` not provide proper vertical alignment for this particular line?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, booktabs, makecell

I am trying to align table cell contents using `\makecell`. It strikes me as very strange that (in the same table), one row gets aligned vertically as intended while the other does not. I want the words 'Component' and 'Impedance' to be bottom-aligned with 'Voltage-Current Relationship'. This should be done using the option `[b]`, I think.

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X X}
        
        \makecell[b]{Component} & \makecell[b]{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & \makecell[b]{Component} & \makecell[b]{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & \makecell[b]{Impedance}
        \\
        
        \makecell[b]{top \\ center \\ bottom} & \makecell[t]{top \\ center \\ bottom} & \makecell[c]{top \\ center \\ bottom} & \makecell[t]{top \\ center \\ bottom} & \makecell[c]{top \\ center \\ bottom}
        \\
        
    \end{tabularx}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because the column width is to small for content in cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine the X column and use only one X.[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c c c c X}
    \hline
    \makecell[b]{Component} & \makecell[b]{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & \makecell[b]{Component} & \makecell[b]{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & \makecell[b]{Impedance}
    \\\hline
    
    \makecell[t]{Component} & \makecell[t]{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & \makecell[t]{Component} & \makecell[t]{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & \makecell[t]{Impedance}
    \\\hline
    
    \makecell[c]{Component} & \makecell[c]{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & \makecell[c]{Component} & \makecell[c]{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & \makecell[c]{Impedance}
    \\\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Very easy with the new package `tabularray`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec = {ccccX},
    width = \linewidth,
    row{1}={valign=b},
    row{2}={valign=t},
    row{3}={valign=m},
      }
    \hline
    Component & {Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & Component &{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & Impedance\\ \hline
    Component & {Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & Component &{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & Impedance\\ \hline
    Component & {Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & Component &{Voltage-Current \\ Relationship} & Impedance\\
    \hline  
\end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

With the braces `\\` can be used inside the cell.
Note that the rows are also vertically centered.

[image: y]